# Filter rows in SQL by sub-query/ joins

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a table of user, product and month.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (user VARCHAR(1),product VARCHAR(1),month INT);
INSERT INTO USERS (user,product,month) VALUES 
("A","X",9),("A","X",10),("A","X",10),("A","Y",11),
("B","Y",12),("B","X",10),("C","X",10),("D","Z",11),("D","X",9);
```

How do I count the number of users of a certain product only (possibly also in a specific month)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join a derived table where you get the users only using product `X` by using aggregation and checking if the minimum product equals the maximum product. Then use `count(DISTINCT ...)`.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT u1.user)
       FROM USERS u1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT u2.user
                               FROM USERS u2
                               GROUP BY u2.user
                               HAVING min(u2.product) = max(u2.product)
                                      AND min(u2.product) = 'X') upx
                       ON upx.user = u1.user;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have an attempt by brute-force sub-query, could you please give some comments to help me improve? Mainly because I am less familiar with table joins and kind of reserve them for joining two different tables..

Comment: @NetUser5y62: Yours is very close to mine. The only thing is that `IN` *may* perform worse than a join when the result in the subquery is large. Using a join *may* give the optimizer more chances. So people tend to use joins over `IN`. But when in doubt compare the plans. They might have equal costs.